# How long does it take to grow crops in Pokémon Legends: Arceus?

Tags: pokemon-legends-arceus

In Jubilife Village, you can pay Colza to grow crops. These crops take time to grow and cannot be collected until they've been harvested.

How long does it take for crops to grow? Do different crops take different amounts of time to grow?

[image: Selecting a crop to grow]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to various guides ([here](https://twinfinite.net/2022/02/pokemon-legends-arceus-farming-system-explained/) and [here](https://www.thegamer.com/pokemon-legends-arceus-complete-farm-unlock-ingredients-guide/)), time is not a direct factor to make your harvest grow. Your harvest will be ready to collect based on doing activities in the overworld, which varies based on what you have planted:

- Apricorn - Catch 8 Pokemon
- Medicinal - Catch 8 Pokemon
- Vegetable - Catch 12 Pokemon
- Mushroom - Catch 12 Pokemon
- Berry - Catch 12 Pokemon
- Mint - Catch 20 Pokemon

Comment: It looks like the only qualifier for growing crops is how many Pokémon you've caught.